# How do I get Location header in soapui

Tags: http, request, xmlhttprequest, soapui

I have a Http request to get a user level token and I got it to work in Jmeter using Script recorder then , I just copied all values headers and parameters as in Jmeter to SoapUi and created the variables for sessionDataKey to get the same token in SoapUi and it actually don't retrieve the same results on the Soapui Response headers.

I see two differences between the responses in Soap and Jmeter.

For Authorize test step:

In jmeter I can see a Response header " Location " in Soap not (notice this one has the value I need)
example:

**Location:** https://The Url of the customer/path/path1/#access_token=fdcfb626b142cc1c3575f4eae154f38a&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=70871

For get SessionDataKey test step:

In jmeter I can see a Response header
 **Set-Cookie:** dtCookie=3$C726269DFD45081379EC3D044AEDE19C

meanwhile I cant seem to get those two response headers in Soapui

I dont mind if I dont get the dtCookie value what I really need its the token , but I suspect I need to get the dtCookie value to the Authpart as In jmeter dynamically takes it its not a problem but SoapUi does not make this job

I believe its about some setting in SoapUi preferences

Any Ideas guys ?

Comment: Does anyone know? help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using another method for token

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable de custom property Follow Redirects:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScsJa.png)